# Subject of the verb quedar in the third person

Tags: gramática, categorías-gramaticales

If we have a sentence like:

> No me queda más madera.

Is "madera" the subject of the verb queda or does queda not have a subject here? If it does not have a subject would we call that a "sujeto tácito" or can a "sujeto tácito" only be a personal pronoun like yo/tú/nosotros?

The RAE gives this example in the second entry for quedar: https://dle.rae.es/quedar

> Me quedan tres euros.

So it seems like "tres euros" is indeed the subject. However, if I go with:

> Me queda más que un poco de madera.

It seems like I just have 3 complements ("más que": CC de Cantidad, "un poco": CC de Cantidad, "de arroz": CC de materia). So depending on the example, I go back and forth on whether this use of quedar has a clear subject or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subject is the entity that does the action expressed by the verb. The verb is always conjugated to agree with the subject, as stated [in the DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/concordancia):

> b) Concordancia verbal (coincidencia de número y persona). Es la que se establece entre el verbo y su sujeto: *Esos cantan muy bien*.

"Quedar" in your sentences means "to be left, to remain, to be still present". It is conjugated in the third person, so the subject must be a third person. In

> No me queda más madera

the subject is therefore **más madera**, as "mas madera" is what does the action of "not being left". In

> Me quedan tres euros

the subject is **tres euros**, for the same reason. In

> Me queda más que un poco de madera

the subject is the whole clause **más que un poco de madera**. Inside this clause, "más" is a comparative pronoun, and "que un poco de madera" is a relative clause, where "que" is a conjunction ("nexo") and "un poco de madera" is the subject of the relative clause. If you go [here](http://www.analisissintactico.com/ejemplos.html), you can see many examples of syntactic analysis of sentences with "queda" and with "más que".

Comment: "que" is a conjunction, not a relative word after "más". See 2.2 here: https://www.rae.es/dpd/que

Comment: To further check that "tres euros" is the subject by concordance with the verb, note that the verb is singular in "me queda un euro" and remains singular in "nos queda un euro". Hence "un euro" is the subject. This sentence has the same structure as other verbs such as "gustar".

Answer (score 0):

Perdóname que te lo explique en español. Tienes la oración:

> No me queda más madera.

Para entenderla mejor, podrías hacer la transformación a:

> A mí no me queda más madera.

Que es lo mismo que decir:

> Yo ya no tengo más madera.

Entonces, en tu oración original, tendrías a "Yo" como sujeto tácito. También podrías hacer en tu oración original la pregunta "¿A quién no le queda más madera?", y la respuesta sería "A mí", que viene a ser uno mismo, o sea, "Yo". Espero haberme explicado bien. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Bienvenido/a al sitio! La pregunta que hay que hacer para encontrar el sujeto es "¿Quién?", no "¿A quién?". La pregunta "¿A quién?" encuentra el complemento directo o el indirecto, como en este caso. En "Me queda madera", igual que en "Me gusta la madera", "madera" es el sujeto, y "me" es un complemento indirecto.